# Set user value from service data to FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, formbuilder

For my Angular Project I have a user profile and i want to put values of user in Form control.
I've tried many things but in don't have the result I want
I want to set values of User dynamically from my service

Here's my form.html

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nom :</label>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastname">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-lock pl-3"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Prenom :</label>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-lock pl-3"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email :</label>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-lock pl-3"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sauvegarder</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my form.ts

```
me!: Me
signupForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({})

constructor(private meService: MeService,  private fb: FormBuilder,) {
  this.CurrentUser()
}

CurrentUser(){
  this.meService.me().subscribe(
    result => {
      this.me = result
    }
  ) 
}
get lastname(): FormControl {
  return this.signupForm.get('lastname') as FormControl;
}

get firstname(): FormControl {
  return this.signupForm.get('firstname') as FormControl;
}

get email(): FormControl {
  return this.signupForm.get('email') as FormControl;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
    lastname: [
      this.me.lastname,
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(30),
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z éèàâëê'-]+$"),
      ]
    ],
    firstname: [
      this.me.firstname,
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(30),
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z éèàâëê'-]+$"),
      ]
    ],
    email: [
      this.me.email,
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
      ],
    ],
  })
}
```

And i'm getting those errors :
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'lastname'
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'firsname'
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'email'

How can I handle this ? please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial errors I suspect are because you first define your FormGroup as an empty object, thus it doesn't have those values. Setting at least some sort of skeleton for it would probably fix those. getters are fired constantly, if you were to put a break point in one you would see that it keeps getting hit all the time, so odds are that at load time before the form had a chance to be hydrated yet, you are trying to get a control that doesn't exist yet.

```
signupForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        firstname: new FormControl(),
        lastname: new FormControl(),
        email: new FormControl()
    })
```

Conversely, it would probably be better to just define it as `signupForm: FormGroup` and then check for undefined in the getter itself. Ex:

```
get email(): FormControl {
  return this.signupForm?.get('email') as FormControl;
}
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that you are making, what I suppose, is an API request. The code doesn't really wait for it to be complete, it is not blocking, so a more appropriate thing to do would be to build your actual form after you get the results build.

```
this.meService.me().subscribe(
    (result: Me) => {
      if(result) { 
         this.me = result

         //build your form here.
      }         
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question has already an answer, but I'll try to give a more compact solution, I think that this question should have an higher rating since retrieving and parsing data from a service to a form control is a very common scenario and there are not similar questions on this website. I've tested the following solution with angular version 7 and 8, but it should work also with different versions.

Assuming that the data retrieved by the service has the given format:

```
{
  lastname: string,
  firstname: string,
  email: string
}
```

you can simply create a form that follows this structure (as you did)

```
this.formItem = this.formBuilder.group({
  lastname: [''], // here validators and so on
  firstname: [''],
  email: ['']
});
```

> Here the important thing is that for every simple field you use a
> FormControl, for an object a FormGroup and a FormArray for an array.

then in your component you can simply write something like this:

```
this.meService.me().subscribe(
    (result: Me) => {
      if(result) { 
         this.formItem.setValue(result);
      }         
    }
  )
```

and the form will be correctly filled. You can use this approach for every kind of data as long as you know the structure of the data you are retrieving. **There is anyway an important exception**, if you are retrieving an array you have to know in advance the length of the array, this is because of the way the `setValue(...)` of the `FormArray` is implemented. Here it is the current implementation of such a method:

```
setValue(value, options = {}) {
        this._checkAllValuesPresent(value);
        value.forEach((newValue, index) => {
            this._throwIfControlMissing(index);
            this.at(index).setValue(newValue, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: options.emitEvent });
        });
        this.updateValueAndValidity(options);
    }
```

as you can see the method iterates over the object you pass and it does a call to `this.at(index)`, at this point if you declare a FormArray with one element, but you have an object with more elements you will get an exception. I think that this behaviour is very annoying so I've created a custom FormArray class that is capable of resize the controller before to procede to setting the value. Of course this is a basic solution, but I hope it can be a good starting point to overcome this limitation.

```
import {
  AbstractControl,
  AbstractControlOptions,
  AsyncValidatorFn,
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  ValidatorFn
} from "@angular/forms";

export class DynamicFormArrayControl extends FormArray {

  constructor(controls: AbstractControl[], private fb: FormBuilder, validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null, asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null) {
    super(controls, validatorOrOpts, asyncValidator);
  }

  resize(value: any[]) {
    value.forEach((newValue, index) => {
      if (typeof newValue === 'object'){
        this.push(this.fb.group(newValue));
      } else if (Array.isArray(newValue)) {
        this.push(new DynamicFormArrayControl([], this.fb));
      } else {
        this.push(this.fb.control({}));
      }
    });
  }
  setValue(value: any[], options?: { onlySelf?: boolean; emitEvent?: boolean }) {
    this.resize(value);
    super.setValue(value, options);
  }
}

// in your component
formItem = this.formBuilder.group({
    lastName: [''],
    firstName: [''],
    email: [''],
    adresses: new DynamicFormArrayControl([], this.formBuilder), // let's say you need this array (an array of strings for example)
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // as you can see no changes here
    this.meService.me().subscribe(
(result: Me) => {
  if(result) { 
     this.formItem.setValue(result);
  }         
}
```

)
}